# Creating a MySQL Database with a Specific Character Set and Collation

Tags: mysql

When creating a MySQL database with `CREATE SCHEMA`, it uses MySQL's default character set and collation. But I want to change that.

How do I create a MySQL Database with a specific character set and collation?

Comment: Did you ever check the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html)?

Comment: @Pred: Yes, and that's where I copied the answer below. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29744532/445438).

I prefer to quickly find answers in SO, and that's why I posted this here. So that when I later need this again, I can look here.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS someDatabase
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = 'utf8' DEFAULT COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
```

and if the database is already created,  then you can alter is like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE SCHEMA `my_database`
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ;
```